# cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: linux, linux-mint

This is probably happening after upgrading linux mint from 19.1 to 19.2 tina

```
$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  2.7G     0  2.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     544M  8.3M  536M   2% /run
/dev/sda5      ext4       19G   18G   31M 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.7G   74M  2.6G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.7G     0  2.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3      fuseblk    94G   69G   25G  74% /mnt/34ADC09A5E6352AC
/dev/sda4      fuseblk   112G   78G   35G  70% /mnt/1CEE91ED7C738E10
/dev/sda6      ext4       73G   20G   50G  29% /home
tmpfs          tmpfs     544M   52K  544M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Are you using **Timeshift**? If so, what does `sudo timeshift --list` show?

Answer (score 5):

You're out of space on your root filesystem, which includes `/tmp`:

> ```
> Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
> /dev/sda5      ext4       19G   18G   31M 100% /
> ```

You need to make some space. If you've just upgraded you can try `apt clean` (or `apt-get clean` if you prefer).

Comment: i ran that command and the Use% is now /dev/sda5      ext4       19G   18G  218M  99% /

Comment: @SagarPardhi if that's not enough you'll need to find where all the space on your root partition has been used. Two furher places to check are in `/root` and under `/var/log`.